# Prepping '0' value to NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

In CodeIgniter, I want to prep a value returned from a form so that if it is a `0`, it will actually be inserted as `NULL`.

I created a function outside of my controller class:

```
function prep_zero_to_null($int)
{
    if ($int == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return $int;
    }
}
```

And at the form validation, I do:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category_id', 'Category', 
                                  'required|integer|prep_zero_to_null');
```

However, CI still tries to insert zeroes as `'0'` in the database, which breaks one of my foreign key constraints.

Interestingly enough, if I replace `NULL` by, say, `25` in the `prep_zero_to_null` function, CI will indeed recognize it and insert `25` instead of `'0'`. So my prepping function is indeed getting called, but CI won't allow `NULL` as a result of it and instead converts it to `'0'`.

How can I achieve what I want?

**Edit**: For those wondering, the `category_id` field does allow null:

```
`category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
```

And the exact error is:

```
INSERT INTO `articles` (`category_id`, `order`, `title`, `text`) 
VALUES ('0', '0', 'test', 'test')
         ^
      Should be NULL

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`db`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) 
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: I'm betting you should be returning the string null instead of the constant: `return 'NULL';` But then again, if that is quoted in the query you won't get the effect you desire.

Comment: Well I guess the corresponding database column does not allow NULL values and has '0' as it's default value.

Comment: Does your table column allow NULLs?

Comment: In you DB, is your column type `integer`?  Does it allow `null`? May be you have type `integer default 0 not null`?

Comment: Yes, the table column `category_id` allows NULL and has it as a default value (it's necessary because `category_id` has to be nullable to fulfill its foreign key constraint).

Also, using `'NULL'` as a string doesn't work (it actually tries inserting a string in the DB, not the keyword).

The exact field definition is: `\`category_id\` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at this quickly I think the problem is your $int == 0. Is $int an actual 0 type integer or is it a string? In which case the proper check would be $int == '0'.

Comment: No, because I'm doing a loose comparison (`==` instead of `===`). According to the PHP doc, `0 == "0"`. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Moreover, even if I replace the whole function body with just `return NULL`, I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter validation functions doesn't set the field value based on what you return, your validation function should either return TRUE or FALSE to state that something is valid or not.

If you're after changing the value of something, you'll need to accept variable by reference and modify it in the function then you can return TRUE so it passes the validation.

The best solution would be to make the check before inserting the data into database & not relying on the validation library to do this kind of dirty work.

Comment: I would've thought the second sentence of your answer is the key to this problem, but valid prepping functions such as `trim`  or `md5` do not work by referencing the first argument, but rather by returning a new value. And as the doc says, `Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc.`.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right on this one, Could you try it this way? if ( (int) $int == 0 ) return NULL;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert null to the database you need to return a string with the value "null".

```
function prep_zero_to_null($int) {
    return ($int == 0) ? 'NULL' : $int;
}
```

Comment: That does not work. It will attempt to insert `'NULL'` (and not `NULL` the keyword) in the query, which is different in MySQL syntax.

Comment: Oh okey. I'm not used with Code igniter. But you should not add additional quotes in your query. Is Code Igniter doing that automatically?

Comment: Yes, as it should, given a string, it can only interpret a value as such and quote it appropriately for database queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just unsetting the variable. It's a bit ugly, but it should return NULL for the value then.

[Tested here.](http://codepad.org/fJDFs7Aq)

Comment: It's more than a bit ugly, you're returning an unassigned variable (to which a standard PHP installation will verbally complain with a notice). Moreover, the problem is not that my function doesn't actually return a `NULL` (it does), but that CI ignores that and still inserts `'0'`.

Comment: Yeah, it was just a proof of concept, because I wasn't sure what the exact problem was. It appears that CodeIgniter just doesn't like the NULL value at validation and only allows it directly set into the database. Strange, you might be better off submitting a bug into their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an issue at the GitHub bug tracker for CodeIgniter, as this appears to be a bug.
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2563

Right now, the workaround at model level is the following:

```
$category_id = prep_zero_to_null($this->input->post('category_id'));

$data = array
(
    'category_id' => $category_id,
    'order' => $this->input->post('order'),
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'text' => $this->input->post('text')
);
```

**Edit**: Apparently, this is the right approach, as there should only be strings at validation/controller level.